# I can not get user's ip address in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

here is the code

```
    Vue.mixin(windowMixin)
    export default {
    name: "App",

    methods: {
        getIpAddress(){

            localStorage.getItem('ipAddress') ? '' : localStorage.setItem('ipAddress', Response.data);
            this.$axios.get('https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace', function(data) {
                console.log(data)
                })
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getIpAddress();
    }
};
```

Result is telling me that I have saved user's ip address as "undefined"
Please help me out, I'm new at Front end

Comment: What is `Response.data`? Where is that defined?

Comment: should you get an error because you try to access an property from `undefined`? also you should check with `null` instead of `""`

Comment: @Phil  I think i wrote it horribly .  Can you describe how should codes have been in answer field ?

Comment: @Ifaruki Yeap i changed it to null

Comment: Are you only wanting to get the IP address from the CloudFlare API if it's not already in `localStorage`?

Comment: @Phil yes exactly. I want to get only Ip address.

Comment: That's not what I asked. You seem to be checking if you already have something in `localStorage` but it's not very clear from your code. Is this code meant to get the IP address only if it's not already in `localStorage`?

Comment: @Phil and I answered Exactly, additional: I want to get only Ip address

Comment: Ok, thanks for clearing that up. It was your _additional_ bit that threw me

Comment: @Phil thank you too !!! It worked  looks like i started learning Javascript too.

Comment: @JakhongirAlikhanov i have added simple solution for this u can take a look it'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing the response from CloudFlare's `trace` API isn't super easy since it is not JSON.

I would use a custom response transformer to parse the data into something usable.

Assuming you want to set the `ipAddress` in local storage only if it's not there already, try this

```js
methods: {
  async getIpAddress () {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("ipAddress")) {
      const { data: { ip } } = await this.$axios.get("https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace", {
        responseType: "text",
        transformResponse: data =>
          Object.fromEntries(data.trim().split("\n").map(line => line.split("=")))
      })
      localStorage.setItem("ipAddress", ip)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is really working smoothly, But I have to write this function in Vuex too ,
but there were also `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response`  How am i going to fix it ? I have googled it but could not find the solution

Comment: Why are you adding an `Authorization` header?

Comment: If you've added an Axios interceptor, please add it to your question. You would need to skip adding additional headers for this particular request and how you do that depends on how you've implemented adding them

Answer (score 2):

As above url have cors issue i have come up with new url try this

```js
getIpAddress() {
    this.$axios.get("http://ipinfo.io/json").then(({ data }) => {
    localStorage.getItem("ipAddress")? "" : localStorage.setItem("ipAddress", data.ip);
    });
},
```

Comment: @Kamlesh Paul I tried , but console was telling me this
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

Comment: @JakhongirAlikhanov can u check now it should work fine

Comment: @KamleshPaul I have tried so many times but not working or maybe I am not good enough to try your code
`GET http://ipinfo.io/json 403 (Forbidden`